# Can Blender VSE sync the video and audio with VFR strips?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

After done editing, I exported only to see that audio and video do not sync. I know what the problem is - the project's video strips have a variable frame rate. But is there a way to make Blender sync them despite that? I don't want to encode every clip that I have with a CFR.

Comment: check having the timeline > playback > av sync setting enabled (default is off), as a start.

Comment: Thanks, but it is on already. The sync disappears only when exported.

Comment: Blender does not do variable frame rate decode. Sorry, you'll have to transcode to use the VSE in sync

Comment: Oh well, thanks! I just encoded all the clips anyway. But still, for some odd reason Handbrake hasn't worked properly on Windows for me, only on Linux. The files are smaller and at a constant frame rate, yes, but Blender can barely handle them, so editing and rendering is very slow.

Comment: My guess is that the screen dimensions of your recording is quite large. Blender decompresses your video into full color frames, have a look at your memory as you scrub through the timeline, I expect that you will be using most of the available ram. Consider making proxies.

Comment: Yeah, it's 1080p 60fps, but raw footage renders a couple of times faster than encoded footage that has less filesize. I think it's a codec bug or some incompatibility, since I've done it hundreds of times, but only on Windows this happens. I ought to get another video encoder, but the problem is I don't know any besides Avidemux, which has always failed me. I'd need one that is capable of simply encoding files of the same name into another folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender does not allow you to decode variable frame rates. Sorry, this is because Blender is only aware of one frame at a time and expects to play 1 frame per frame. In other words it is temporaly blind (can't look ahead) and doesn't understand that you may want to hold the current frame for a period of time. You'll have to transcode to a compatible Codec to use the VSE in sync with audio.

Comment: this could be a good feature request, perhaps... even if a corner case probably.

Comment: Support for variable frame rates opens up a can of worms regarding time stamps.  It is not entirely unreasonable to find files with discontinuous time stamps (advertisement splices, concatenated transport streams) and then there's the simple case of a file that was encoded at a frame rate that does not match the project fps.

Answer (score 5):

When I have had to deal with variable-frame-rate video I use ffmpeg to render it to PNGs at a fixed frame rate.

```
ffmpeg -i screencap.mp4 -vf fps=30 $(OD1)/%04d.png
```

ffmpeg will "resample" the video temporally, probably duplicating some frames.  It might even drop frames if your source video has some really short inter-frame intervals.  Just pick `fps=` to match the rate of your VSE project to make your life easy.

Once you have the PNG sequence you can use that as the source for your VSE strip.

*edit*: Since you have mentioned you have a large library of clips, I would create a makefile

```
/var/tmp/cfr/%/0001.png: %.mp4
        ffmpeg -i $< -vf fps=30 /var/tmp/cfr/$*/%04d.png
```

Alternately, you could have a shell script that iterates through the video files to perform the conversion

```
for f in "$@"; do
    d=/var/tmp/cfr/$(basename $f .mp4)
    ffmpeg -i $f -vf fps=30 $d/%04d.png
```

Comment: I've hundreds of video clips, how do you expect me to manage such a mess! :D

Comment: ffmpeg can run through all the clips in a folder and create new files for you.